# Query performance issues when using MATCH and SELECT together OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm facing a problem with a query in OrientDB.

```
SELECT FROM (
   MATCH 
      {class: article, as: article}.in('authorOf'){as: author} 
   RETURN article, author
) ORDER BY createdAt desc SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
```

As you see I want to fetch the last 50 most recent articles with their corresponding author. The problem I'm facing is that the subquery first iterates over all my articles then passes it down to the parent and then it gets filtered. This is obviously not very effective, because all the articles are loaded into memory when I only need 50 of them.

Does anyone know a better approach without having to use multiple queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try with

```
select @rid as article,in('authorOf')[0] as author from article order by createdAt desc SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
```

With this one I'm getting a sligthly better performances, but nothing extreme.

**EDIT following Luigi's comment**

Create an index on `createdAt` property:

```
CREATE INDEX article.createdAt ON article (createdAt) NOTUNIQUE
```

---

PS

I'm not sure that the `order by` in your query is working well

Comment: To have a good performance in this query, you have to define an index on `createdAt` property

Comment: @LuigiDell'Aquila yeah! with a `NOTUNIQUE` SBTREE index I have a great improvement in performance. - about 200ms vs 20ms

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some new insights.